# Remove a tab from a tabGroup's navigation without removing it from the tabGroup?

Tags: iphone, titanium, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I'm using Appcelerator Titanium to build an iPhone app. I currently have a tabGroup control that links to the major sections of the app, including the home screen.

What I'd like to do is remove the "Home" tab **only from the navigation, without removing it from the tabGroup object.** So, for example, I'd still be able to call `tabGroup.setActiveTab(0)` and it would take me to the home screen, but the tabs at the bottom wouldn't have a "home" button.

Is this even possible? If so, how can I do it?

**Notes:** I do **not** want to hide the whole bar, just a single tab. I also do **not** want to remove the screen from the underlying object, just the navigation UI. Also, I'm only developing for iPhone and don't care if other platforms aren't supported, so iPhone-only solutions are acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take the home screen out of the tab group completely and manage displaying it and transitioning to it separately; in the end, it will be a cleaner solution.

Comment: I'm actually not worried about "cleaner," because it only needs to last one version. After that, my company is rewriting it in ObjC. We've ended up making do with what we have and removed another screen and made it a child of the home screen, though.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `tab.hide()` or when creating the tab setting it to `visible: 0`?